# How to extract the value in name using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

```
<project id=""><name>Main account</name><balance>1236.59</balance><htmlchar>$</htmlchar><currency>HKD</currency><balancem>1236.59</balancem></project>
```

I want to extract the value `Main account` from `name` using beautiful soup. I know I can extract value from `balance` using `foo.balance.string`, but seems not applicable for `name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<project id=""><name>Main account</name><balance>1236.59</balance><htmlchar>$</htmlchar><currency>HKD</currency><balancem>1236.59</balancem></project>""")

print soup.find("name").string
```

Result:

```
Main account
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you.

```
 html_doc = "<project id=''><name>Main account</name><balance>1236.59</balance><htmlchar>$</htmlchar><currency>HKD</currency><balancem>1236.59</balancem></project>"
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
    print soup.find('name').string
```

Comment: this is identical to the answer that was posted way before yours, what is different about yours?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I did't see that reply before my answer. Now only I saw his reply.